# Computing 2 values from input fields and displaying them in a label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do the following. Take one input field, add it to another, then display it in a label on a form. I had this previously where I was adding 2 values and then displaying them in an input but that's no longer wanted. Here's the code for that. I'm assuming i'd append the label to display the new total but I could not get it to work properly.

```
var $recurringCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_monthly_cost_value');
var $recurringTotalCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value');
var $totalRetailAmountField = $('#am_oie_string_total_monthly_cost_value').closest('.field');
var $totalRetailAmountFieldLabel= $totalRetailAmountField.find('label');
var $oneTimeCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value');

function calcTotalRetailVal() {
    var num1 = $oneTimeCostField.val();
    var num2 = $recurringTotalCostField.val();
    var result = parseFloat(num1.replace(/,/g, '')) + parseFloat(num2.replace(/,/g, ''));
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        $totalRetailAmountFieldLabel.val(result.toFixed(2));
     //Append here?
    }   
}
    calcTotalRetailVal();
      $oneTimeCostField.on("keydown keyup", function() {
        calcTotalRetailVal();
    });
      $recurringTotalCostField.on("keydown keyup", function() {
        calcTotalRetailVal();
    });
```

Comment: Use `$totalRetailAmountFieldLabel.text(result.toFixed(2));` instead of `val(...)`

Comment: Duh! Thank you for that.